# Name of binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics

Does anyone recall the name of the following binomial identity?

Let $k_1,\ldots,k_m$ be non-negative integers and $n\geq \sum_{i=1}^mk_i$. Then

$$\binom{n+m-1}{k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_m+m-1}=\sum_{n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_m=n}\binom{n_1}{k_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\binom{n_m}{k_m}$$

I used that for some computation regarding the negative hypergeometric distribution. It describes a combinatorial way to create a committee with at least $k_1,\ldots,k_m$ members from $m$ groups.

Comment: It looks like a sort of upside-down [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Generalized_Vandermonde's_identity) to me, but I don't know of a name for it.

Comment: In (unsuccessfully) looking for a name I found some friends: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73015) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1312180) (in which Brian M. Scott also calls it an upside-down Vandermonde identity... maybe it'll catch on!).